# initial velocity/rotation for cloth sim?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I want to simulate (cloth sim) a rolling tire that suddenly runs out of air. When I set keyframes up to the point where the simulation starts, the tire stops abruptly. The result is a cloth sim of a standing tire, which I don't want. I want the tire to roll and maintain speed and rotation when the cloth sim starts. This works for rigid body simulations. does it work for cloth sims?

Comment: Rigidbody sims have a checkbox to inform the sim that it will be controlled by the animation system.  I don't see that option for cloth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For desired effect seems to me easier use **Lattice** to deform the Tire ...

---

Add Lattice, scale in object mode, increase W segments like to 10.
Add Lattice modifier to Tire object ...
[image]

Add Shape Keys to animate deformation as needed ...
[image]
[image]

Animate Wheel Rotation ... depending on usage.

[image]
https://pasteall.org/blend/2b0139358ae7450896765c5006edf897

Comment: very nice.....!!